# US Bureau of Labor Statistics (blsAPI package) - blsQCEW() function doesn't fetch data for years before 2015

Tags: r, api

I am trying to get county-level industry data from the US BLS. I'm using their blsAPI package and blsQCEW() function to get the data. The function works for years after 2015 but not for the years before. Does anyone know a work around? or know why it is not working for prior years?

```
# install.packages(blsAPI)
library(blsAPI)
blsQCEW('Industry', year= '2017', quarter = "a", industry='21') # works
blsQCEW('Industry', year= '2001', quarter = "a", industry='21') # doesn't work
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
# In addition: Warning message:
# In file(file, "rt") :
#  cannot open URL 'https://data.bls.gov/cew/data/api/2001/a/industry/21.csv': HTTP status was #'404 Not Found'
```

Comment: Looks like [according to the documentation](https://www.bls.gov/bls/api_features.htm) the API only provides data for the last 20 years. 2001 is outside that range. Earlier data is not available from the website and therefore cannot be accessed by the R package.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks. I tried to get 2010 data using blsQCEW() as well and that also didn't work also :( The other function blsAPI() from the package allowed me to get data from 2001 to 2020 for the other datasets.